# Rails 3: How do I generate a compressed file on request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to generate compressed files on request.

I have this controller

```
def create    
    send_data generate_tgz("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/example.txt"), :filename => 'export.tgz'    
end
```

But it gives me a method not found on generate_tgz.

Is it a plugin or gem? Do I need to require anything? Can I generate a zip file instead?

Edit:

```
def generate_tgz(file)
    system("tar -czf #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export-result #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export")
    content = File.read("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export-result")
    #ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(content)    
end
```

This creates a tgz, but when I decompress it I get app/c3ec2057-7d3a-40d9-9a9d-d5c3fe3ffd6f/home/tmp/export/and_the_files

I would like it to just be: export/the_files

Comment: Are you talking about the example given on this page http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html? I don't think there's any such method implemented in Rails. It was just an example.

Comment: @Dogbert: Yes, that's the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method doesn't exist. You can easily create it using [ActiveSupport::Gzip](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Gzip.html).

```
def generate_tgz(file)
  content = File.read(file)
  ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(content)
end
```

Comment: Nice! The only thing I had to change is :filename => 'export.tgz' to :filename => 'export.zip'. And how do I bundle many files into one?

Comment: To bundle many file at once you need to create an archive. Rails doesn't support this by default.

Comment: I managed to use a shell call to make an archive. Now it works well, except that it creates a rather non friendly directory hierarchy. Check the edit.