# Zipping a directory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, rubyzip

How do i go about zipping a directory in ruby on rails? I've tried rubyzip without success. I don't need to zip the contents of the dir individually just zip the dir itself.

Comment: What's difficult to figure out? Yarin tried rubyzip, didn't like it.  Just wants to zip a directory and needs to know the best way to do it. What's confusing?

Comment: What does it mean to zip a directory, but not its contents?  All of the answers zip the directory including the contents, so none of them have addressed the question as asked.

Answer (score 14):

You are going to have to loop through the items in the directory to add an entry in the compressed file.

```
def compress(path)
  gem 'rubyzip'
  require 'zip/zip'
  require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

  path.sub!(%r[/$],'')
  archive = File.join(path,File.basename(path))+'.zip'
  FileUtils.rm archive, :force=>true

  Zip::ZipFile.open(archive, 'w') do |zipfile|
    Dir["#{path}/**/**"].reject{|f|f==archive}.each do |file|
      zipfile.add(file.sub(path+'/',''),file)
    end
  end
end
```

> http://grosser.it/2009/02/04/compressing-a-folder-to-a-zip-archive-with-ruby/

Another way to do it with a command

```
Dir["*"].each do |file|
  if File.directory?(file)
    #TODO add OS specific,
    #  7z or tar .
    `zip -r "#{file}.zip" "#{file}"`
  end
end
```

> http://ruby-indah-elegan.blogspot.com/2008/12/zipping-folders-in-folder-ruby-script.html

**Update**

Thank you Mahmoud Khaled for the edit/update

for the new version use `Zip::File.open` instead of `Zip::ZipFile.open`

Comment: the second way doesn't wok on many hosting environments because they don't include zip.exe in their VM. Heroku for instance doesn't.

Comment: But what the way are better? To use ruby or zip/gzip utility on production and why?

Comment: First one is better, because it is using a Ruby library.  The second one just calls zip.exe in a Windows environment

Answer (score 0):

You can create an archive of the directory using tar  `tar -cvf your_dir.tar your_dir/`

and then compress the tar in rails using -

```
def gzip_my_dir_tar(your_dir_tar_file)
  content = File.read(your_dir_tar_file)
  ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(content)
end
```

Its already answered at [Rails 3: How do I generate a compressed file on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030583/rails-3-how-do-i-generate-a-compressed-file-on-request)

Comment: Zip is completely different from tar + gzip