# Rubyzip fail to add a file with a same name from another folder [Zip::EntryExistsError]

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

Using the following test tree folder for example:

```
- test1
- folder2
  - test1 # This is the file rubyzip will break on.
  - test2
```

And copied this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509802/zipping-a-directory-in-rails):

```
path = File.expand_path path
archive = File.join(__dir__, File.basename(path)) + '.zip'
FileUtils.rm archive, force: true

Zip::File.open(archive, Zip::File::CREATE) do | zipfile |
  Dir["#{path}/**/**"].reject{|f|f==archive}.each do | item |
    basename = File.basename(item)
    zipfile.add(basename, item)
  end
end
```

It fails because there is two files having the same name even if their are not in the same directory (`test1` in my example).

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Should I post as an issue to the gem `rubyzip` if that is not the correct behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @simonoff ([here](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/323)), I shouldn't use the basename but the full relative path so Rubyzip could make the difference between `test1` and `folder2/test1`.

Here is a code fixing it:

```
basename = File.basename path
dirname = File.dirname path
internal_path = path.sub %r[^#{__dir__}/], ''

archive = File.join(dirname, basename) + '.zip'
FileUtils.rm archive, force: true

Zip::File.open(archive, Zip::File::CREATE) do | zipfile |
  Dir["#{internal_path}/**/**"].map{|e|e.sub %r[^#{internal_path}/],''}.reject{|f|f==archive}.each do | item |
    zipfile.add(item, File.join(internal_path, item))
  end
end
```

There is certainly a much cleaner way to do it.